# PNG Sprite hover flicker

Tags: css, hover, png, sprite, transition

I am trying to animate this image properly for a hover in and out. 
I have it 90% of the way there. Wor some reason if you hover in and out quickly, you can see the sprite moving in the background

Is there a fix or a better way to do this?

http://www.elevux.org/watermelon/

Thanks!!!

```css
.wrapper {
 width:600px;
 height:600px;
 overflow:hidden;
 margin:20px;
}
 
.watermelon {
 width:600px;
 height:600px;
 background:url(http://www.elevux.org/watermelon/watermelon-sprite.png) left top;
transition:background .5s steps(23, end);
display:block

}


.watermelon:hover {
 background-position:-13800px top;
 cursor:pointer
 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="watermelon"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the transition onto the hover selector, seeing as that is when you want the animation to take place.

https://jsfiddle.net/gzk3mcyr/

```
.wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 20px;
}

.watermelon {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  background: url(http://www.elevux.org/watermelon/watermelon-sprite.png) left top;
  display: block;
}

.watermelon:hover {
  background-position: -13800px top;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background .5s steps(23, end);
}
```

Comment: Hey Seemly, This works however it removes the out animation which is a cool part!

Comment: OK, how about the following edit to the fiddle? The only 'downside' is the animation on page load (which can be negated using javascript), but I think it could entice interaction with the element. https://jsfiddle.net/gzk3mcyr/1/